ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unknown authentication strategy "jwt" Error: Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"
When i do request to endpoint that guarded with Jwt strategy i get this error

ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"

so there is my
jwt-auth.guard.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}

jwt.strategy.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { IUser } from '../../types/types';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretKey: configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
    });
  }

  async validate(user: IUser) {
    return { id: user.id, email: user.email };
  }
}

auth.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { UserModule } from '../user/user.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './strategies/local.strategy';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtStrategy } from './strategies/jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        secret: configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
        signOptions: { expiresIn: '30d' },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
})
export class AuthModule {}

auth.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get, Post, Request, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { LocalAuthGuard } from './guards/./local-auth.guard';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './guards/jwt-auth.guard';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    console.log(req.user);
    return this.authService.login(req.user);
  }

  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Get('profile')
  getProfile(@Request() req) {
    console.log('some profile');
  }
}

So when i do request to profile end point with valid token i get this

i expect output "some profile in my console"

You're using Strategy from passport-local instead of from passport-jwt. That strategy inherently has a name of local, which means that there is no strategy with the name jwt for passport to find. Change the Strategy import from passport-local to passport-jwt and it should be fine
